# Sublime Text 2: Can plugins render HTML?

Tags: phpunit, textmate, sublimetext2

I'm looking to add some visual appeal to Stuart Herbert's great sublime-phpunit plugin. Currently, it displays the text output of PHPUnit in a little window at the bottom of the screen.

I have a custom PHP printer class that displays PHPUnit output as HTML. What I'm trying to find out is if it's possible for Sublime Text to display this output as HTML. I'm just seeing source at the moment. This was really easy to do in TextMate, by just picking the output window type. Is there a similar control in Sublime Text 2?

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to display rich output as of Build 2217.

You can [vote for this feature](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/35383-preview-window-for-build-output-and-other-things/) on Sublime Text's official ideas forum.